# phantomJS не открывает сайт

Tags: phantomjs

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
    page.reason = resourceError.errorString;
    page.reason_url = resourceError.url;
};

page.open(
    "https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/de/USA-Staat-Anleihe-US912810RT79",
    function (status) {
        if ( status !== 'success' ) {
            console.log(
                "Error opening url \"" + page.reason_url
                + "\": " + page.reason
            );
            phantom.exit( 1 );
        } else {
            console.log( "Successful page open!" );
            phantom.exit( 0 );
        }
    }
);
```

при первом запуске скрипт сработал и дальше просто виснет. Остальные сайты нормально открывает. Что может быть причиной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

смог nightmare js на базе node js.